# R calculating differences on a pivoted tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm struggling some beginner issues with R and tables. I spend most of my data visualisation time in Tableau but I want to be able to replicate work in R to take advantage of the report generation capacity of RMarkdown and the StatCanR library to allow me to pull data in from their Statistics Canada's CANSIM/CODR tables. My coding experience is along the lines of C, C++, Java, Javascript and Python with all but Python learnt in college around the turn of the millenium.

I am extracting rates of certain types of crimes and have created the following table.

````
```# A tibble: 4 × 11
  Violations                        `2011` `2012` `2013` `2014` `2015` `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`
  <chr>                              <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Total, all Criminal Code violati…  5780.  5638.  5206.  5061.  5232.  5297.  5375.  5513.  5878.  5301.
2 Total violent Criminal Code viol…  1236.  1199.  1096.  1044.  1070.  1076.  1113.  1152.  1279.  1254.
3 Total property crime violations …  3536.  3438.  3154.  3100.  3231.  3239.  3265.  3348.  3512.  3071.
4 Total drug violations [401]         330.   317.   311.   295.   280.   267.   254.   229.   186.   176.
````

I have filtered away data that is more than ten years old and only for certain crimes.

```
# Pivot the data
table_01 <- pivot_wider(table_01 %>%select("REF_DATE","Violations","VALUE"),names_from=REF_DATE, values_from=VALUE)

table01a<-table_01 %>%select(2020,2019,2011)
)
mutate(
  ten_year_change = 2020-2011,
  one_year_change = 2020-2019
  )
```

I've been messing around with different libraries including tidyverse and dplyr. I want the code to calculate the diffence between the most recent two years and the difference between the most recent year and (most recent year - 10 years ago). The idea is to generate a new report when Statistics Canada updates their data.

This code is above absolutely not what I want. I do want the years that I calculate differences to not be hard coded so I don't have to edit the code in six months.

My suspicion is that I am not getting my head around the R way of doing things, but if I can get a push in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Below is the TLDR full RMarkdown script:

```
    ---
    title: "CJS Statistical Summary"
    output:  word_document
    date: '2021-10-05'
    ---
    ` ` `{r setup, include=FALSE}
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    #load libraries
    #install.packages("tidyverse")
    #install.packages("statcanR")
    #install.packages("flextable")
    #install.packages("dplyr")
    
    library("tidyverse")
    library("statcanR")
    library("flextable")
    library("dplyr")
    
    setwd("~/R_Scripts") # change for a Windows-style path if ran in Windows.
    
    #set language
    language <-"eng"
    
    # Load dataset Incident-based crime statistics, by detailed violations
    CODR_0177 <- statcan_data('35-10-0177-01', language)
    
    # Code not written for these CODR tables
    #CODR_0027 <- statcan_data('35-10-0027-01', language)
    #CODR_0038 <- statcan_data('35-10-0038-01', language)
    #CODR_0029 <- statcan_data('35-10-0029-01', language)
    #CODR_0022 <- statcan_data('35-10-0022-01', language)
    #CODR_0006 <- statcan_data('35-10-0006-01', language)
    ` ` `
    
    ## Table 1
    
    ` ` `{r table_01, echo=FALSE}
    # Develop table 1 - Crime Stats
    # =============================
    
    # Find most recent ten years
    years <- distinct(CODR_0177 %>% select("REF_DATE")) 
    years <- arrange(years,desc(REF_DATE))%>% slice(1:10)
    
    # Copying the crime stats table so it isn't altered in case we need to reuse it.
    table_01 <- CODR_0177
    
    # Remove unused columns
    table_01 <- table_01 %>% select("REF_DATE","GEO","Violations","Statistics","UOM","VALUE") %>% filter(REF_DATE %in% years$REF_DATE)
    
    # Keep only national data
    table_01 <- table_01 %>% filter(GEO == "Canada")
    
    # Keep only crime rate
    table_01 <- table_01 %>% filter(Statistics == "Rate per 100,000 population")
    
    # Keep only certain Violations
    display_violations <- c("Total, all Criminal Code violations (excluding traffic) [50]","Total violent Criminal Code violations [100]","Total property crime violations [200]","Total drug violations [401]" )
    table_01 <- table_01 %>% filter(Violations %in% display_violations)
    
    # Pivot the data
    table_01 <- pivot_wider(table_01 %>%select("REF_DATE","Violations","VALUE"),names_from=REF_DATE, values_from=VALUE)
       
    #calculating year to year differences
    table01a<-table_01 %>%select(2020,2019,2011)
    )
    mutate(
      ten_year_change = 2020-2011,
      one_year_change = 2020-2019
      )

    # Edit look and feel for report using Flextable
    flex_table_01<-flextable(table_01)
    flex_table_01<-theme_vanilla(flex_table_01)
    flex_table_01<-add_header_row(
      flex_table_01,
      values=c("","Rates per 100,000 population","% change"),
      colwidths=c(1,10,2)
    )
    flex_table_01<-add_header_row(
      flex_table_01,
      values=c("Incidents Reported to Police (Crime Rate)"),
      colwidths=c(13)
    )
    
    flex_table_01 <- align(flex_table_01, i = 1, part = "header", align = "center")
    flex_table_01 <- fontsize(flex_table_01, i = NULL, j = NULL, size = 8, part = "all")
    flex_table_01 <- colformat_double(flex_table_01, big.mark=",", digits = 0, na_str = "N/A")
    
    flex_table_01
    
    #remove temporary files
    rm(years)
    rm(display_violations)
    rm(table_01)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is much easier with the data in "long" format. Below is an example with fake data. We use the `lag` function to get changes over different time ranges. Once you've added the changes over various timescales, you can subset and reshape the data as needed to create your final tables.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
d = tibble(
  REF_DATE = rep(2010:2020, each=4),
  Violations = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 11),
  value = sample(100:200, 44)
) 

d
#> # A tibble: 44 × 3
#>    REF_DATE Violations value
#>       <int> <chr>      <int>
#>  1     2010 A            184
#>  2     2010 B            178
#>  3     2010 C            169
#>  4     2010 D            105
#>  5     2011 A            131
#>  6     2011 B            107
#>  7     2011 C            116
#>  8     2011 D            192
#>  9     2012 A            180
#> 10     2012 B            175
#> # … with 34 more rows
```

```
d1 = d %>% 
  arrange(Violations, REF_DATE) %>% 
  group_by(Violations) %>% 
  mutate(lag1 = value - lag(value),
         lag10 = value - lag(value, n=10))

print(d1, n=23)
#> # A tibble: 44 × 5
#> # Groups:   Violations [4]
#>    REF_DATE Violations value  lag1 lag10
#>       <int> <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     2010 A            184    NA    NA
#>  2     2011 A            131   -53    NA
#>  3     2012 A            180    49    NA
#>  4     2013 A            174    -6    NA
#>  5     2014 A            189    15    NA
#>  6     2015 A            132   -57    NA
#>  7     2016 A            139     7    NA
#>  8     2017 A            108   -31    NA
#>  9     2018 A            101    -7    NA
#> 10     2019 A            147    46    NA
#> 11     2020 A            193    46     9
#> 12     2010 B            178    NA    NA
#> 13     2011 B            107   -71    NA
#> 14     2012 B            175    68    NA
#> 15     2013 B            164   -11    NA
#> 16     2014 B            154   -10    NA
#> 17     2015 B            153    -1    NA
#> 18     2016 B            115   -38    NA
#> 19     2017 B            171    56    NA
#> 20     2018 B            166    -5    NA
#> 21     2019 B            190    24    NA
#> 22     2020 B            117   -73   -61
#> 23     2010 C            169    NA    NA
#> # … with 21 more rows
```

We can also do multiple lags as once:

```
d2 = d %>% 
  arrange(Violations, REF_DATE) %>% 
  group_by(Violations) %>% 
  mutate(map_dfc(1:10 %>% set_names(paste0("lag.", .)), 
                 ~ value - lag(value, n=.x)))

d2
#> # A tibble: 44 × 13
#> # Groups:   Violations [4]
#>    REF_DATE Violations value lag.1 lag.2 lag.3 lag.4 lag.5 lag.6 lag.7 lag.8
#>       <int> <chr>      <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     2010 A            184    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  2     2011 A            131   -53    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  3     2012 A            180    49    -4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  4     2013 A            174    -6    43   -10    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  5     2014 A            189    15     9    58     5    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  6     2015 A            132   -57   -42   -48     1   -52    NA    NA    NA
#>  7     2016 A            139     7   -50   -35   -41     8   -45    NA    NA
#>  8     2017 A            108   -31   -24   -81   -66   -72   -23   -76    NA
#>  9     2018 A            101    -7   -38   -31   -88   -73   -79   -30   -83
#> 10     2019 A            147    46    39     8    15   -42   -27   -33    16
#> # … with 34 more rows, and 2 more variables: lag.9 <int>, lag.10 <int>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>